# I can log but Not double click an element of local web page to extract the resulting page / using selenium:python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I walked around a lot of posts and couldn't perfor any change for double clicking on a my web page element bellow :

```
 <div  class="tbl-content">
                <table class="hoverTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="alarms">
                    <tbody>  <tr ondblclick="DoubleRowClick(this, '9', '2019-06-12 15:59:49', '2019-06-12 16:00:55');" id="NotRead">
                        <td class="NotReadCell">2019-06-12</br>15:59:49 UTC </td>
                        <td class="NotReadCell"> NAME 1 </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class='slideTwo'>
                                <input type='checkbox' value="None" id="slide9" name="check" onchange="stateCheck(this, '9');">
                                <label for="slide9"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>  <tr ondblclick="DoubleRowClick(this, '10', '2019-06-13 09:32:54', '2019-06-13 09:33:36');" id="NotRead">
                        <td class="NotReadCell">2019-06-13</br>09:32:54 UTC </td>
                        <td class="NotReadCell">  NAME 2 </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class='slideTwo'>
                                <input type='checkbox' value="None" id="slide10" name="check" onchange="stateCheck(this, '10');">
                                <label for="slide10"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>  <tr ondblclick="DoubleRowClick(this, '11', '2019-06-13 09:34:47', '2019-06-13 09:35:10');" id="NotRead">
                        <td class="NotReadCell">2019-06-13</br>09:34:47 UTC </td>
                        <td class="NotReadCell">  NAME 3 </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class='slideTwo'>
                                <input type='checkbox' value="None" id="slide11" name="check" onchange="stateCheck(this, '11');">
                                <label for="slide11"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>  <tr ondblclick="DoubleRowClick(this, '12', '2019-06-13 09:36:38', '2019-06-13 09:37:44');" id="NotRead">
                        <td class="NotReadCell">2019-06-13</br>09:36:38 UTC </td>
                        <td class="NotReadCell">  NAME 4 </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class='slideTwo'>
                                <input type='checkbox' value="None" id="slide12" name="check" onchange="stateCheck(this, '12');">
                                <label for="slide12"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>  <tr ondblclick="DoubleRowClick(this, '13', '2019-06-13 12:22:35', '2019-06-13 12:23:41');" id="NotRead">
                        <td class="NotReadCell">2019-06-13</br>12:22:35 UTC </td>
                        <td class="NotReadCell">  NAME 5 </td>
                        <td>
```

And my code is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://1.2.3.4:82805/")
assert "Home" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("pwd")

#print (elem)
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("0000")
elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.get("http://1.2.3.4:82805/menu.php")
driver.maximize_window()
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='NotRead']")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.double_click(element).perform()
```

And my errors are :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects_Drivers\webBrowser.py", line 19, in <module>
    actions.double_click(element).perform()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py", line 83, in perform
    action()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py", line 277, in <lambda>
    Command.MOVE_TO, {'element': to_element.id}))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I tried a lot of solutions but i need to know if  the probleme is in my python coding way or it is not possible to do what i need to do with this HTML web interface.

And my question is is that possible to click it if there is no id?
Or how can I find  my button to click. I can understand that the web interface is not well coded but I am not allowed to change its code or add elements. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: The html has multiple elements with `id="NotRead"`, but id is supposed to be unique.

Comment: what element do you want to double click on?

Comment: one by one NAME 1 then NAME 2 then NAME 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `find_elements_by_xpath` will return list of elements, and in your code you are passing list rather element.

So,Change the below line

> element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='NotRead']")

to

> element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='NotRead']")

Comment: Waw thank you for your quick answare  i will try it now

Comment: Do you mean the html table data? or just some filter results on the page.

Comment: Yes It is resolved i only need to wait 6minutes before accepting you replayed so fast ^^

Comment: My application is a Qt c++ application and I only need to verify that an information was added and for this I need to read the alarms inside and they are not visible till i double click so i automated it. And now i need to get the information inside in c++ app

Comment: You can open another post with the html of the page after double click, so that we can take a look.

Comment: Ha ha ! Yes, I think I replied quickly on the post. You can accept it when you have the option available :-)